# Save a specific filed from an object inside ng-option? And set a first default value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array of Objects that contain this data:

```
vm.myCars= [
        {
           Id: 1,
           name:"Ford"
        },
        {
           Id: 2,
           name:"Buick"
        }
  ]
```

I want to show inside the ng-option the name of the car but when the user select a car i want to save the Id in a variable (an object).

```
 <select class="form-control input-sm"                
                            ng-model="vm.pickedCar.Id"                           
                            ng-options="i.name for i vm.myCars"></select>
```

I also want to set the first value inside the select box. Any suggestions?

Comment: `ng-options="i.Id as i.name for i in vm.myCars"`

Comment: and in the controller `vm.pickedCar = { Id: vm.myCars[0].Id };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this `ng-options` syntax:

```
ng-model="vm.pickedCar" ng-options="i.Id as i.name for i in vm.myCars"
```

Then init the value in the controller:

```
vm.pickedCar = 1;
```

See example:

```js
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller("testCtrl", function ($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.pickedCar = 1;
    vm.myCars= [
        {
           Id: 1,
           name:"Ford"
        },
        {
           Id: 2,
           name:"Buick"
        }
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="TestApp" ng-controller="testCtrl as vm">
    pickedCar: {{vm.pickedCar}}
    <br>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="vm.pickedCar" 
            ng-options="i.Id as i.name for i in vm.myCars"></select>
</div>
```